# Not able to fully externalize link function of a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to externalize a link function of a directive.
I am able to but I cannot access $rootScope or $window inside that function

What is existing ::

```
mapModule.directive('map', function ($rootScope,$window) {
    return {
        templateUrl: resource + 'partials/maps.html',
        controller: 'mapController',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controllers) {
            $rootScope.something = something.
            $window.something = something 
        }
    };
});
```

what i want

```
function mapLinkFunction(scope, element, attrs, controllers) {
    $rootScope.something = something//$rootScope is undefined
    $window.something = something //$window is undefined
};

mapModule.directive('map', function ($rootScope,$window) {
    return {
        templateUrl: resource + 'partials/maps.html',
        controller: 'mapController',
        link: mapLinkFunction
    };
});
```

I have tried injecting both of them into mapLinkFunction but does not work

Comment: @NickKenens I dont want to do that. The reason why i want to keep the link outside is I have more than one directive that has to use mapLinkFunction. If i define it within the directive then it will become specific to it.

Comment: Try using a `service` for reusable components within an angular project & inject the service into your directive, that's what [services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) are made for.

Comment: That should do exactly what you need. Allowing you to reuse the function in many other directives, controllers, etc...